# Setting RichTextBox visibility is giving me a runtime error of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: silverlight

I'm trying to set the visibility of my RichTextBox to Collapsed, but I keep getting a runtime error of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Here's my xaml:

```
<RichTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,12,0,0" Name="contentBox" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="330" Width="390" IsReadOnly="True">
</RichTextBox>
```

and my xaml.cs:

```
contentBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Error is pointing at the cs line

Comment: Did you try setting your object reference to the instance of an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I resolved the issue properly.  But my RichTextBox was embedded deep into the xaml (maybe the fifth child).  I just relocated it to outside of the second last parent, and then was able to set its settings (was no longer null).

So it looks like I tried setting properties on my control, when it wasn't fulling instantiated yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run InitializeComponents(); before doing anything in the codebehind with the objects declared in the XAML

```
InitializeComponent();
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't paste all my code, but I do run InitializeComponent() before trying to set the visibility.